# The convergence of the series after integrating term-by-term

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am interested in the integral

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i A x} e^{- Bx^2 - \lambda x^4}, $$

for some real values $A$, $B>0$ and $\lambda >0$.

One way to tackle this integral is to expand in $\lambda$
and integrate term by term

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i A x} e^{- Bx^2} - \lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4 e^{i A x} e^{- Bx^2} + \ldots ,$$

which I can do analytically now and get simply

$$ I = G \left(1 - \frac{\lambda}{16} \frac{1}{B^4} (A^4 - 12 A^2 B + 12 B^2)+\ldots \right) ,$$

where $G$ is the Gaussian integrals $G = \sqrt{\pi/B} \exp(-A^2/4B)$.

However, I am not sure under which assumptions am I allowed to do all this.
Is this expansion formally convergent for any values of $\lambda >0$? And if so (or not) how can I see it or prove it?

Comment: This is alternating series, right? So for convergence it's enough that the general term decreases in absolute value. You should try checking that. I think we can derive the general formula for all the terms

Comment: Yes tnx. I had a typo in the second equation. Yes, the general terms can be computed by some higher derivatives of the Gaussian part. But this leads me to some complicated forms involving Faa di Bruno's formula... I was hoping it would have been somehow a known thing when I can or can not expand the exponential under the integral.

Comment: Since in this case every term is a convergent integral, the only thing left to determine is whether or not the resulting series converges. Maybe we can check that without explicit formulas

Comment: ok so maybe the case when $A=0$ is a good starting point. Then the remaining integrals are relatively easy. But I still get something that in absolute value diverges as $n^n$, and I'm not sure how to check if the alternating sign can save this.

Answer (score 1):

since $A\in\mathbb{R}$ you can say that:
$$\left|e^{iAx}\right|=1\,\,\,,\forall|x|<\infty$$
and so to see if your integral converges we just need the following integral to converge:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-Bx^2-\lambda x^4\right)dx$$
which since $B,\lambda>0$ clearly converges.

---

In terms of whether you are allowed to expand to a series like that, you are since:
$$\exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\,\,,\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$
and so the series converges to the function for all values you are interested in.

---

In terms of the series and working out values, it may be nicer to make a substitution and get this as a series of Gamma functions?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it formally, the series only converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, so because you are integrating over the half real line, you destroy the convergence of the series by switching the two. You however still have an asymptotic series in $\lambda$.

Comment: @Zachary could you maybe expand a bit on that? How do I see exactly that the convergence is destroyed and why is the remaining series then asymptotic in $\lambda$?